# How do I make a Graphic Button?

Tags: commerce

I want to make a button on location on a php file that currently is just a hyperlink.
Currently, the code segment appear in a browser with the text "Donate now", but I want it to be a paypal button instead.

All this is part of a paypal module I have set up in Drupal.  I have already figured out the proper way to use a .css file with this module to modify another aspect of it.  And now I want to change the textual hyperlink to a paypal button.

The line of code in question looks like this in the paypal_donations_single.tpl.php file:

```
<a href="#" class="donation-submit-button"><?php echo t($variables['submit_value']); ?></a>
```

The hyperlink text appears in the browser as "Donate now".  This text appears in the .inc file includes\paypal_donations.admin.inc:

```
$form[$type_key]['paypal_donations_' . $type_key . '_submit_value'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Form submit text'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#description' => t('The button text when someone sends the form'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('paypal_donations_' . $type_key . '_submit_value', 'Donate now'),
);
```

This line of code is of particular interest to me:

```
'#type' => 'textfield',
```

Maybe there is an example somewhere that has a graphic as a '#type'.

I have an extensive list of modules already and when I did a grep-style dos/cmd file findstr command I found many examples.  The one that looks the most promising is:

```
'#type' => 'image_button'
```

and the accompanying code looks like this:

```
 $form['go'] = array(
      '#type' => 'image_button',
      '#src' => $options['image'],
      '#submit' => array('ctools_jump_menu_submit'),
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('ctools-jump-menu-button'),
      )
```

based on what I can observe, I assume that all I need to do is change this:

```
$form[$type_key]['paypal_donations_' . $type_key . '_submit_value'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Form submit text'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#description' => t('The button text when someone sends the form'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('paypal_donations_' . $type_key . '_submit_value', 'Donate now'),
);
```

into this:

```
$form[$type_key]['paypal_donations_' . $type_key . '_submit_value'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Form submit text'),
  '#type' => 'image_button',
  '#src' => $options['image'],
  '#description' => t('The button text when someone sends the form'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('paypal_donations_' . $type_key . '_submit_value', 'Donate now'),
);
```

I only need to figure out how to best assign this '#src" variable.  When I looked into the $options settings, the complexity and flexability reached new heights and I think now is a good time to ask for some help online with more experienced Drupal scripters and developers.  Perhaps there is an easier way to assign this value a hardcoded path and image name.

I looked around at the code to see how this array $options is used, I could not see where the 'image' part is assined to a graphic.

I need some help, advice, and guidance.

On the chance that I have been going down the wrong direction, I did a grep search on "donation-submit-button" since this is the class name of the html tag I am interested in:

```
<a href="#" class="donation-submit-button"><?php echo t($variables['submit_value']); ?></a>
```

But the only place it appears to be defined is in a .js file:

```
paypal_donations\js\paypal_donations.js:    $(".donation-submit-button").click(function(){
paypal_donations\templates\paypal_donations_recurring.tpl.php:  <a href="#" class="donation-submit-button"><?php echo t($variables['submit_value']); ?></a>
paypal_donations\templates\paypal_donations_single.tpl.php:  <a href="#" class="donation-submit-button"><?php echo t($variables['submit_value']); ?></a>
```

and all that is denoted is the functionality, not the apparance:

```
//When user click Donate now
$(".donation-submit-button").click(function(){
  var post_form = false;
  //If any checkbox is checked set true
  if($('INPUT:checkbox:checked',$(this).closest('.donation-form')).length > 0)
    post_form = true;

  //If Other has value set true
  if($('INPUT:text',$(this).closest('.donation-form')).val() != '')
    post_form = true;

  if(post_form){
    $(this).closest('.donation-form').submit();
  }
  else{
    alert(Drupal.t('Please enter your donation amount'));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is by doing it using css only.

Inspect the element with your browser and find the div class that belongs to the "Donate Now". By looking at your code I suspect it is **donation-submit-button**

So all you gotta do is:

- Add a background image
- Set the font-size to 0px to hide the "Donate Now" text.

Example:

```
.donation-submit-button a{ background-image: url("paypal-logo.jpg");
    background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.donation-submit-button a{ display:block; height: 60px; width: 80px; border: solid red; }

.donation-submit-button a{ font-size: 0px; }
```

See it in action, check out this [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gsboofm2/31/)